# How can I get more than one line and dots on a single graph?

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to put multiple plots on a single graph, but whenever I try, the lines always show up on new graphs. I have this:

```
1A<-filter(collapsed,task=="type1" & target_presence=="A")
plot(1A$set_size_num, 1A$rt, ylim=c(0,4000), xlim=c(0,30), pch=19, col="green", xlab="Set Size", ylab="Response Time (msec.)")
legend(x=0, y=4000, pch=c(19,1,19,1), col=c("green","green","red","red"), cex=0.7, legend=c("1A","1B","2A","2B")) 
1Af<-lm(data=1A,rt ~ set_size_num) 
summary(1Af) 
abline(1Af, col="green")

1B<-filter(collapsed,task=="type1" & target_presence=="B")
plot(1B$set_size_num, 1B$rt, ylim=c(0,4000), xlim=c(0,30), pch=1, col="green", xlab="Set Size", ylab="Response Time (msec.)")
1Bf<-lm(data = 1B,rt ~ set_size_num)
summary(1Bf)
abline(1Bf,col="green")
```

How can I get the lines and points on the same plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call plot only once in the first instance, then call lines for subsequent plots.

You should provide reproducible data to test your code, but you can try this.  I believe you also meant to color code the second set of lines "red" based on your legend.

On a programming note, object/variable names should not start with a number, e.g. `1A`, `1B`, instead use `A1`, `B1`... these are used below.

```
A1 <- filter(collapsed, task=="type1" & target_presence == "A")
A1f <- lm(data = A1, rt ~ set_size_num) 
summary(A1f)
B1 <- filter(collapsed, task=="type1" & target_presence == "B")
B1f <- lm(data = B1, rt ~ set_size_num)
summary(B1f)


plot(A1$set_size_num, A1$rt, ylim=c(0,4000), xlim=c(0,30), pch=19, col="green", xlab="Set Size", ylab="Response Time (msec.)")
lines(A1$set_size_num, A1$rt, col="green")
points(B1$set_size_num, B1$rt, pch=1, col="red")
lines(B1$set_size_num, B1$rt, col="red")
abline(A1f, col="green")
abline(B1f, col="red")
legend(x=0, y=4000, pch=c(19,1,19,1), col=c("green","green","red","red"), cex=0.7, legend=c("1A","1B","2A","2B"))
```

Comment: i didn't get the dots for 1B, only for 1A

Comment: I thought you wanted lines?  If you want dots then replace `lines` with `points`.  I edited the code above.

Comment: See edited code, once you call plot, you can subsequently add lines and points.

Comment: are they lines of best fit? That's what I need

Comment: If you want the regression line only, the `abline` plots the `lm` fit.  Just remove the `lines`, keep the `plot`, `points` and `abline`.

Comment: I want the regression lines and points for both of them on the same graph

Comment: Set linetype, `lty=3` or `lty='dotted'`, e.g. `abline(A1f, col="green", lty=3)`. You can find possible linetypes here: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/line-types-in-r-lty